# How to use nextScene.gotoandplay link using class property (external code.as)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

i try this code but i got error

```
package  {

                        import flash.display.SimpleButton;
                        import flash.display.MovieClip;
                        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

                        public class np extends SimpleButton {

                        public function np() {
                                                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickF);
                                                }
                                                private function clickF(e:MouseEvent):void{
                                                MovieClip(this.root).nextScene(),gotoAndStop(1);

                        }
            }

}
```

Call to possibly undefined method gotoanStop

Note: just i want to go next scene

Comment: Thx guys

I got the solution



MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();